# How do people understand the imagery in Ezekiel 1?

Tags: ezekiel, angels, throne-of-god

Ezekiel is a very imagistic chapter - you have a whirlwind, 4 cherubs with 4 faces and 4 wheels.

What do these represent? and how do they fit into the wider old testament?

Answer (score 1):

The theophany of Eze 1-3 is one of many such throughout the OT.  Here is a sample:

- Ex 3:1-12 - Most meets YHWH at the burning bush in the desert and is commissioned as prophet and leader of Israel
- Ex 19:16-25 - Mt Sinai on fire with earthquakes, etc
- 1 Kings 19:9-18 - a message from God to encourage Elijah and commission his successor, Elisha.
- Ps 18:8-16 - YHWH rides on cherubim with the earth shaking - a message of assurance to David
- Isa 6:1-6 - "Holy, Holy Holy" by the six seraphim in God presence
- Jer 1 - Jeremiah is commissioned as prophet complete with God touching Jeremiah's lips (similar to Isa 6)
- Amos 9 - YHWH standing beside the altar delivers a very stern and dramatic  message

The theophany in Eze has a number of similarities to those listed above: mysterious, dramatic, with a very important message, the commissioning of Ezekiel as a prophet.

Thus, it appears that such theophanies are used by God to make indelible impressions on the minds of the observers for various functions:

- commissioning a prophet or leader as with Moses, Isaiah, Ezekiel, Jeremiah, Elijah-Elisha, etc.
- delivering a very important message

Lastly, there are clear allusions to these theophanies in the book of revelation; for example, Rev 4 alludes to Isa 6 and Eze 1.